# Change output of DateTime in json_encode

Tags: php, json, datetime

Is somehow possible to change output of `json_encode(['date' => $dateTimeObj])`?

Now it prints

```
{
    "date": {
        "date": "2016-10-27 11:23:52.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Paris"    
    }
}
```

I would like to have output like this

```
{
    "date": "2016-10-27T11:23:52+00:00"
}
```

My first idea was to create my own DateTime class which will extends DateTime and override jsonSerialize, but DateTime does not implement JsonSerializable interface and __toString did not help too.

I'm using PHP 7.0.8.

I meant something like this

```
<?php    
MyDateTime extends \DateTime implements jsonSerialize 
{
    public function jsonSerialize() // this is never called
    {
       return $this->format("c");
    }
}

$datetime = new MyDatetime();

$output = [
    'date' => $datetime;  // want to avoid $datetime->format("c") or something like this everywhere
];

json_encode($output);
```

This code now output

```
{
    "date": {
        "date": "2016-10-27 11:23:52.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Paris"    
    }
}
```

I would like to have

```
{
    "date": "2016-10-27T11:23:52+00:00"
}
```

Comment: `json_encode()` does not manipulate any data you give it. If you put the date into the object/array you are encoding the way you want to see it it will stay that way. So fix the code that adds the date

Comment: Basically… manually format the date into a string before you `json_encode` it.

Comment: @deceze yes, it is probably the only way. I have to return date for articles, comments, threads... and more... So I thought it will be possible to convert it somehow automatically at one place.

Comment: what is the format for that type of date `2016-10-27 11:23:52.000000`, I'm guessing `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ???` what's the last `.000000` ?

Comment: Microseconds. They are added since some 5.x version of the PHP. This is `Y-m-d H:i:s.u` format according to http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After changing a few details, notably the interface name, your code works just fine for me on PHP 7.0.14.

```
<?php

class MyDateTime extends \DateTime implements \JsonSerializable
{
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
       return $this->format("c");
    }
}

$datetime = new MyDatetime();

$output = [
    'date' => $datetime,
];

echo json_encode($output);
// Outputs: {"date":"2017-02-12T17:34:36+00:00"}
```

Comment: OMG, shame on me. Thank you!