# Encode/Decode Json with datetime objects symfony php

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, decode

I have a array with datetime objects .The array lookks like as follows

```
$advanceresult= array:68 [▼
      "contact" => array:1 [▶]
      "policyBranch" => ArrayCollection {#38322 ▶}
      "assuranceContact" => ArrayCollection {#38337 ▶}
      "info" => null
      "withSurplusShare" => false
      "withSurpassedSurplusShare" => false
      "withoutPremiumInvoice" => false
      "withoutPremiumInvoiceRange" => array:2 [▼
        "start" => DateTime @1577833200 {#38339 ▶}
        "end" => DateTime @1609369200 {#38346 ▶}
      ]
      "showPoliciesFromArchivedContacts" => false
    ]
```

The withoutPremiumInvoiceRange key value is a datetime object.
My problem is when i encode this array as follows

```
$advanceresultencode=json_encode($advanceresult);
json_decode($advanceresultencode, true);
```

and decode it back the datetime objects is looking like as follows

```
enter code here

"withoutPremiumInvoiceRange" => array:2 [▼
    "start" => array:3 [▼
      "date" => "2020-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
      "timezone_type" => 3
      "timezone" => "Europe/Zurich"
    ]
    "end" => array:3 [▶]
  ]
```

I need the data to datetime object.Can anyone help me acheiving this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the datetime without an extra step. You can change the encode process (more info here: [Change output of DateTime in json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282868/change-output-of-datetime-in-json-encode)) but same issue on json_decode.

Here is what you can do on json_decode :

```
<?php

// Here your json as string
$json = ...;

$jsonDecoded = json_decode($json);

$jsonDecoded['withoutPremiumInvoiceRange']['start'] = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d H:i:s.u', 
    $jsonDecoded['withoutPremiumInvoiceRange']['start']['date'], 
    new DateTimeZone($jsonDecoded['withoutPremiumInvoiceRange']['start']['timezone'])
);
```